# Trying to update a date in a table mySql using datagrip IDE

Tags: php, mysql, date-parsing

I am trying to update a date in a certain table in mySQL in the datagrip IDE and I keep on getting the same error message when I run the query:

> [2017-10-20 12:39:28] [HY000][1411] Incorrect datetime value: '2016-04-16 10:00:00 AM' for function str_to_date

```
UPDATE DetailRental
  SET DETAIL_RETURNDATE =  STR_TO_DATE('2016-04-16 10:00:00 AM', '%d/%m/%Y %h:%i %p') 
WHERE RENT_NUM = 1001 AND VID_NUM = 34342;
```

Above is my query and I have searching all over the internet on how to format this and to my knowledge this has been the most consistent but I keep on getting the same error message and my table will not update.

If anyone can help and see what I am doing wrong would be great. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your string has a data in `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS AM` format, but you're asking to parse a date in `DD/MM/YYYY HH:MM AM` format. Your parse string must be the format your string is in.

```
mysql> select STR_TO_DATE('2016-04-16 10:00:00 AM', '%d/%m/%Y %h:%i %p');
+------------------------------------------------------------+
| STR_TO_DATE('2016-04-16 10:00:00 AM', '%d/%m/%Y %h:%i %p') |
+------------------------------------------------------------+
| NULL                                                       |
+------------------------------------------------------------+

mysql> select STR_TO_DATE('2016-04-16 10:00:00 AM', '%Y-%m-%d %h:%i:%s %p');
+---------------------------------------------------------------+
| STR_TO_DATE('2016-04-16 10:00:00 AM', '%Y-%m-%d %h:%i:%s %p') |
+---------------------------------------------------------------+
| 2016-04-16 10:00:00                                           |
+---------------------------------------------------------------+
```